# How can I change my menu state to hide or show my menu in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to get change the menu state either to open or close but I keep getting an empty string.

My code

```
 const [SidebarOpens, setSidebarOpens] = useState(false)

 let menu = "";
const openHandler = () => {

if (!SidebarOpens) {
  setSidebarOpens(true);
  menu = "open";
} else {
  setSidebarOpens(false);
  menu = "close"
}
}


return (
    <div className="mobile-header">
       
        <div className="right-header">
            <IconButton>
                <MenuIcon onClick={() => openHandler()} />
            </IconButton>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

When the open handler function is called on it should change the menu from close to open or from open to close but I get empty string each time I click on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix your problem:

```
const [SidebarOpens, setSidebarOpens] = useState(false);
const [menu, setMenu] = React.useState('');

const openHandler = () => {

    if (!SidebarOpens) {
        setSidebarOpens(true);
        setMenu("open");
    } else {
        setSidebarOpens(false);
        setMenu("close")
    }
};


return (
    <div className="mobile-header">

        <div className="right-header">
            <IconButton>
                <LaunchIcon onClick={() => openHandler()} />
            </IconButton>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`menu` will be set to empty string every time the component renders. You need to put it in a state variable.

```
const [SidebarOpens, setSidebarOpens] = useState(false)
const [menu, setMenu] = useState("");

const openHandler = () => {

if (!SidebarOpens) {
  setSidebarOpens(true);
  setMenu("open");
} else {
  setSidebarOpens(false);
  setMenu("close");
}
}


return (
    <div className="mobile-header">
       
        <div className="right-header">
            <IconButton>
                <MenuIcon onClick={() => openHandler()} />
            </IconButton>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

What do you need the `menu` string for? You already have the state of the menu in `SidebarOpens`.